# Trying to copy cells from one sheet to another through VLookup

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. Sheet 2 has data being pulled in from an Access database using a Macro. There is an account number (ex: 12345) and an account name corresponding to that number (ex: Account A).

On Sheet 1, I have am using VLookup in the Account Name field to look at the Account number in column A, use that value to look up the account number on Sheet 2, and pull the corresponding Account Name from Sheet 2.

I am getting an #N/A error. I believe the issue is related to the fact that the account number in Sheet 2 is being pulled in as "Number as Text". However, the account on Sheet 1 is text.

I tried changing the account on Sheet 2 to be text as well and it still won't work. I also tried writing a macro to format paint from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 so the accounts would literally match.

If I double click on the account number on Sheet 2 and hit enter, it will pull the account name into Sheet 1. So I tried writing a macro to set the account value equal to itself as I had to do that for some other fields but that won't work either.

Has anyone had a similar issue like this before? How can I get the vlookup to recognize the accounts on Sheet 2?

Here is the vlookup I am using on Sheet 1:
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A15,Ledger!A:B,2,FALSE),"")

```
    Sub DATA_RECORDSET_OPEN()
        Application.StatusBar = "OPENING RECORDSET  -  PLEASE WAIT"
        With rstQuery
          .ActiveConnection = cn
          .Source = sqlSelect
          .LockType = adLockOptimistic
          .CursorType = adOpenStatic
          .CursorLocation = adUseServer
          .Open
        End With
      Application.StatusBar = False
     End Sub

    Sub DATA_IMPORT_RECORDS()
      'This section counts the number of rows with data in column "A" and then pastes the information from the query on the first empty row.
        Application.StatusBar = "IMPORTING NEW ROWS OF DATA  -  PLEASE WAIT"
        intRows = Application.CountA(ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A"))
        ActiveSheet.Range("A" & intRows + 1).CopyFromRecordset rstQuery
        Application.StatusBar = False
    End Sub

    'Format painter from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Range("A15").Copy
        Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A2:A500").Select
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

   'Fixes Sheet 2 total formulas by correcting Sheet 2 tab cells
    intCount = Application.CountA(Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A:A"))
        Do Until intCount = 1
            Range("A" & intCount).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("A" & intCount).Value
            Range("B" & intCount).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("B" & intCount).Value
            Range("C" & intCount).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("C" & intCount).Value
            Range("D" & intCount).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("D" & intCount).Value
            Range("E" & intCount).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Range("E" & intCount).Value
            intCount = intCount - 1
        Loop
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code for us to look at?

Comment: The issue is *very* likely due to the number/text formatting: simply wrap your lookup value with a `TEXT` or `VALUE` (depending on the format of the source) function, and the lookup should work just fine. Please [edit] your question to include the actual formula you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` won't find a number if it's looking for text, or text if it's looking for a number.

If Excel is understanding account numbers as string values in the `Ledger` sheet, convert the lookup value to a string using the `TEXT` function:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TEXT(A15,"@"),Ledger!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```

If Excel is understanding account numbers as numeric values in the `Ledger` sheet, convert the lookup value to a number using the `VALUE` function:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(VALUE(A15),Ledger!A:B,2,FALSE),"")
```